# Marginal plots using axis_canvas in cowplot: How to insert gap between main panel and marginal plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

The following came up in a comment to [this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47449321/4975218) When making marginal plots with the `axis_canvas()` function in cowplot, how can we create a gap between the main plot and the marginal plot?

Example code:

```
require(cowplot)

pmain <- ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = cty, y = hwy, color = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  xlab("City driving (miles/gallon)") +
  ylab("Highway driving (miles/gallon)") +
  theme_minimal()

xbox <- axis_canvas(pmain, axis = "x", coord_flip = TRUE) + 
  geom_boxplot(data = mpg, aes(y = cty, x = factor(cyl), color = factor(cyl))) + 
  scale_x_discrete() + coord_flip()
ybox <- axis_canvas(pmain, axis = "y") + 
  geom_boxplot(data = mpg, aes(y = hwy, x = factor(cyl), color = factor(cyl))) +
  scale_x_discrete()

p1 <- insert_xaxis_grob(pmain, xbox, grid::unit(0.6, "in"), position = "top")
p2 <- insert_yaxis_grob(p1, ybox, grid::unit(0.6, "in"), position = "right")
ggdraw(p2)
```

[image]

As we can see in this example, the marginal boxplots directly touch the main plot panel. The goal is to generate some gap. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options:

**Insert empty plot**

We can apply the `insert_xaxis_grob()` / `insert_yaxis_grob()` functions iteratively to insert multiple grobs, one of which can be empty. In this way, we can insert a specified amount of space on either side of the marginal plots. Here I'm showing how to do this on the inside, to generate a gap between the main panel and the marginal plots:

```
# pmain, xbox, ybox are defined as in the question
pnull <- ggdraw() # generate empty plot

p1 <- insert_xaxis_grob(
        insert_xaxis_grob(pmain, xbox, grid::unit(0.6, "in"), position = "top"),
        pnull, grid::unit(0.2, "in"), position = "top")

p2 <- insert_yaxis_grob(
        insert_yaxis_grob(p1, ybox, grid::unit(0.6, "in"), position = "right"),
        pnull, grid::unit(0.2, "in"), position = "right")
ggdraw(p2)
```

[image]

**Create gap in the marginal plots**

Alternatively, since the marginal plots are drawn with ggplot2, we can just specify axis limits that generate space in the appropriate location. I.e., instead of `xbox` and `ybox` in the original code, we define `xbox2` and `ybox2` via:

```
xbox2 <- axis_canvas(pmain, axis = "x", coord_flip = TRUE) + 
  geom_boxplot(data = mpg, aes(y = cty, x = as.numeric(factor(cyl)), color = factor(cyl))) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-2, 4.5)) + coord_flip()
ybox2 <- axis_canvas(pmain, axis = "y") + 
  geom_boxplot(data = mpg, aes(y = hwy, x = as.numeric(factor(cyl)), color = factor(cyl))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-2, 4.5))

p1 <- insert_xaxis_grob(pmain, xbox2, grid::unit(0.8, "in"), position = "top")
p2 <- insert_yaxis_grob(p1, ybox2, grid::unit(0.8, "in"), position = "right")
ggdraw(p2)
```

[image]

To understand what is happening here, let's compare `xbox` and `xbox2` side by side:

```
plot_grid(xbox + panel_border("black"), 
          xbox2 + panel_border("black"), nrow = 1, scale = 0.9)
```

[image]

We see how `xbox2` (on the right) has extra space at the bottom, which was created by starting the axis at -2, even though the first box plot is located at position 1. More information on how to choose the axis ranges for these marginal plots can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47546013/4975218)