# cowplot: How to customize the gaps between main panel & marginal plots by modifying axis limits?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

This is a followup question on one of the solutions provided by @ClausWilke ([see post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542849/marginal-plots-using-axis-canvas-in-cowplot-how-to-insert-gap-between-main-pane)) to insert gap between main panel & marginal plots.
How does one decide the (scale_x_continuous) limits? 
Also, what’ll happen if we used “NA” as the upper limit?

```
# Example with limits set to: (-2,4.5)
require(ggplot2)
require(cowplot)

pmain <- ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = cty, y = hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  xlab("City driving (miles/gallon)") +
  ylab("Highway driving (miles/gallon)") + 
  theme_grey()

xbox2 <- axis_canvas(pmain, axis = "x", coord_flip = TRUE) + 
  geom_boxplot(data = mpg, aes(y = cty, x = 1))  + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-2, 4.5)) + coord_flip()

ybox2 <- axis_canvas(pmain, axis = "y") + 
  geom_boxplot(data = mpg, aes(y = hwy, x = 1)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-2, 4.5))

p1 <- insert_xaxis_grob(pmain, xbox2, grid::unit(0.8, "in"), position = "top")
p2 <- insert_yaxis_grob(p1, ybox2, grid::unit(0.8, "in"), position = "right")

ggdraw(p2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a continuous x-axis scale, you can use `expand_limits` to add some empty space between the main plot and the marginal plots.

For example, your `ybox2` is a single box plot with a continuous x-axis scale. By default, the x-range for this plot is roughly 0.6 to 1.4 (you can see this by running `ggplot(mpg, aes(y=hwy, x=1)) + geom_boxplot()`). The following code sets the lower x-axis limit to 0.2 instead, meaning that about 0.4/(0.8+0.4) = 33% of the x-axis range will be the margin between the main plot and the marginal plot. We do the same for `xbox2`.

```
ybox2 <- axis_canvas(pmain, axis = "y") + 
  geom_boxplot(data = mpg, aes(y = hwy, x = 1)) +
  expand_limits(x = 0.2)

xbox2 <- axis_canvas(pmain, axis = "x", coord_flip = TRUE) + 
  geom_boxplot(data = mpg, aes(y = cty, x = 1))  + 
  coord_flip() +
  expand_limits(x = 0.2)

p1 <- insert_xaxis_grob(pmain, xbox2, grid::unit(0.4, "in"), position = "top")
p2 <- insert_yaxis_grob(p1, ybox2, grid::unit(0.4, "in"), position = "right")

ggdraw(p2)
```

[image]

Comment: Was reviewing this problem once again. Your solution of expand_limits() is an extremely simple, generalizable and useful one. Avoids getting into scale limits, which could vary by type of marginal plot. Great solution! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct. To provide some additional information:

First, you can use the `layer_scales()` function to figure out exactly what the scales limits of a plot are. For example:

```
ybox2 <- axis_canvas(pmain, axis = "y") +  
    geom_boxplot(data = mpg, aes(y = hwy, x = 1))
layer_scales(ybox2)
#$x
#<ScaleContinuousPosition>
# Range:  0.625 -- 1.38
# Limits: 0.625 -- 1.38
#
#$y
#<ScaleContinuousPosition>
# Range:    12 --   44
# Limits: 10.4 -- 45.6
```

Second, it can be helpful to look at the marginal plots in a theme that shows the axes, like so:

```
ybox2 + theme_bw()
```

[image]

We see that the boxplot completely fills the entire x range of the plot, hence there are no margins. If we expand the axis, as suggested in the other answer, we get:

```
ybox2 + expand_limits(x = 0.2) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

In the original figure I had made, with four boxplots, using these methods you can see that the boxplots are at positions 1, 2, 3, 4, therefore it made sense to set the axis range from -2 to 4.5. However, the upper limit of 4.5 wasn't chosen perfectly, and created some additional gap on the other side of the boxplots. The `expand_limits()` approach is probably better.

Comment: As always, thank you for providing a 360 on the problem (adding to the solution by @eipi10)! Until now, I was only using ggplot_build() to understand some nuances of created plots. Henceforth I will use layer_scales() too. 

Perhaps, a good way to use layer_scales() + expand_limits::: find the scale range using layer_scales(). Use expand_limits(x =c(lower_limit_x, upper_limit_x), y = c(lower_limit_y, upper_limit_y)) as required. To maintain symmetry, if required, use range +/- axis_limit